# How to change the "deselected" bar color with brush on dc.js

Tags: dc.js

There is a way to change the color of the deselected bar (i'm talking about the brush selection) on a chart with dc.js?This is [my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPjxd.png)

As you can see i can change the "selected color" but is possible also whit the "deselected"? Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/200) can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deselected color is defined in dc.css, or more specifically, in [dc.scss](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/style/dc.scss) which is used to generate dc.css.

In your own style sheet you can override it, e.g.:

```
.dc-chart rect.deselected {
    fill: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a newbie with dc but i really love to use it.